# error while transfering xampp database file of windows to lampp of linux

Tags: php, xampp

mysql server is not running in lampp where apache and proftpd are running, 
i copied the folder of database and file of ibdata1 from the older xampp of windows xampp/mysql/data/database_folder  and to ubuntu 18.04 lampp/var/mysql and paste it before copying everything was ok but after copying and rebooted machine i get error while opening mysql database
[opening phpmyadmin and xampp it says like in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3whSm.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxd2I.png]

Comment: Why are you copying these data files around in the first place? Create a proper _dump_ of the data, and import it on the target machine …

Comment: now its seem possible but mysql database is not running

Answer (score 0):

Here're some key lines on my.cnf:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

innodb_data_home_dir = /var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/mysql/
```

You could also check the socket and innodb correct or not on your site, and please make sure your db file owner group / user group are same as your mysql folder, please try 'chown' if not.